# Which Q&A site for questions on assigning a MAC ID to a modem?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about using a particular gateway (modem + WiFi combined unit) with Comcast, and which number to give them for the MAC id. I'm trying to figure out which Q&A site would be the best to post this question to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it would be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) per their [help center](https://superuser.com/help):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - **computer hardware**,
> - computer software, or
> - **personal and home computer networking**

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 4):

Super User.

https://superuser.com/

What questions can you ask there?
https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> computer hardware,
>   computer software, or
>   personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> programming and software development,
>   video games or consoles,
>   websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
>   electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
>   issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
>   asking for a shopping or product recommendation,
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!